# Getting iScroll 4 to work with iFrames on Ipad iOS 4.3+

Tags: javascript, ios, iscroll4

I am working on an iPad web application using standard HTML/CSS/JS. Eventually it will be wrapped in Phonegap, but for the time being it will live on the web.

The application delivers HTML5 content from Scribd (converted PDFs) via an iFrame embed. Due to the different orientations of the iPad, and readability of the content, it is necessary to have the content of the iFrame larger than the embedded iFrame.

The issue I've run into is that Apple in their infinite 'wisdom' have taken out the ability to scroll iFrames in iOS 4.3+ (both using 1 and 2 finger scrolls).

I've implemented [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) to get around this however it only seems to work if the user touches outside of the iFrame, even if the whole iFrame is inside the scrolling div.

Has anybody found a workaround / solution for this? Can I disable the iFrame scrolling somehow and give full control to iScroll?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, been hacking at this for days...

Comment: Could you explain me how you managed to make iScroll work with iFrames? It does not work for me.